# Why won't PHP follow symlinks with SELinux enabled?

Tags: php, centos, symlink, selinux

I have a website using propel. I want to put the various config files out of the web root, but propel needs them (such as `schema.xml`, `build.properties`, etc) in the same directory. So, I decided to add symbolic links from the web root to those directories:

```
somesite.com/
  |
  |- public/
  |  |- index.php
  |  |- build -> ../private/build
  |  |- vendor -> ../private/vendor
  |
  |- private/
  |  |- build.properties
  |  |- schema.xml
  |  |- build/
  |  |- vendor/
```

My include path is set thus:

```
set_include_path('vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'build/classes' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

However, when I try to `require_once 'Propel.php';` I get the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(Propel.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/staging/apache/somewebsite.co.uk/public/functions.php on line 5
```

Checking it with `chdir('vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib');` I get the following error:

```
Warning: chdir(): Permission denied (errno 13) in /home/staging/apache/somewebsite.co.uk/public/functions.php on line 5
```

So, it appears PHP/Apache won't follow the symlinks. I have tried the following:

- Checked that the directories are `o+x` so apache can read it
- Added `Options FollowSymLinks` to the directory directive in the apache config (though in the docs it says this is the default setting anyway)
- I also tried `chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_content_t public/vendor/` to change the SELinux type but for some reason it doesn't change

**Update**

I logged in as apache user (`su -s /bin/bash apache`) and ran `cat vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/Propel.php` from inside the `public` directory and it worked just fine. However, I temporarily disabled SELinux and **the error went away**. So of course it must be SELinux.

As I mentioned earlier, I tried:

```
chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_content_t public/vendor/
```

but after doing it, running `ls -alZ` gives me the following for vendor:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. staging developers unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 vendor -> /home/staging/apache/somewebsite.co.uk/private/vendor/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you access those file from the console, when impersonating as the web server user?

Comment: Yeah, `su -s /bin/bash apache` and `cat vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/Propel.php` from inside the `public` directory lists the contents of that file fine.

Comment: What happens if you execute a little php-cli script as the apache user?

Comment: Running `php -r "chdir('vendor');var_dump(getcwd());"` from  the `public` dir outputs `string(61) "/home/staging/apache/somewebsite.co.uk/private/vendor"`

Comment: ok, this means the problem exists only when you use the apache sapi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being the way I was trying to set the SELinux type.

I was running:

```
chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_content_t public/vendor/
```

However, I had to run:

```
chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_content_t public/vendor
```

**without** the trailing slash. Once I did this, everything immediately sprung to life.

**Note:** As I didn't have an `Options` directive in my apache `Directory` config, I didn't have to specify it and it still worked.